# Help required with matrix multiplication notation

Tags: linear-algebra, transpose

Consider the following matrix $\mathbf{H}\in\mathbb{R}^{k \times (M1+M2+1)}$.
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{H} = 
  \left[
  \begin{matrix}
   \mathbf{h}_{-M1}^{}  & \cdots & \mathbf{h}_{-1}^{} & \mathbf{h}_{0}^{} & \mathbf{h}_{1}^{}      & \cdots   & \mathbf{h}_{M2}^{}     
\end{matrix}
\right]
\end{align*}

where $\mathbf{h}_{i}$ is the $i^{th}$ column of $\mathbf{H}$. Now I am defining two new matrics $\mathbf{H_{1}}$ and $\mathbf{H_{2}}$ as
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{H_{1}} &= 
  \left[
  \begin{matrix}
   \mathbf{h}_{-M1}^{}   & \cdots & \mathbf{h}_{-1}^{}      
\end{matrix}
\right]
 \\
\mathbf{H_{2}} &= 
  \left[
  \begin{matrix}
  \mathbf{h}_{1}^{} & \cdots & \mathbf{h}_{M2}^{}     
\end{matrix}
\right]
\end{align*}

Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{H} = 
  \left[
  \begin{matrix}
   \mathbf{H_{1}}  & \mathbf{h}_{0}^{} & \mathbf{H_{2}}     
\end{matrix}
\right].
\end{align*}

and $\mathbf{H^{T}}$ can be written as

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{H^{T}} = 
  \left[
  \begin{matrix}
   \mathbf{H_{1}^{T}}  \\ \mathbf{h}_{0}^{T} \\ \mathbf{H_{2}^{T}}     
\end{matrix}
\right]
\end{align*}

Can I write $\mathbf{H^{}H^{T}}$

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{^{}HH^{T}} &= \left[
  \begin{matrix}
   \mathbf{H_{1}}  & \mathbf{h}_{0}^{} & \mathbf{H_{2}}     
\end{matrix}
\right]
  \left[
  \begin{matrix}
   \mathbf{H_{1}^{T}}  \\ \mathbf{h}_{0}^{T} \\ \mathbf{H_{2}^{T}}     
\end{matrix}
\right]\\
&=\left[
  \begin{matrix}
   \mathbf{H_{1}^{}H_{1}^{T}}  + \mathbf{h}_{0}^{}\mathbf{h}_{0}^{T} + \mathbf{H_{2}^{}H_{2}^{T}}     
\end{matrix}
\right]\tag{*}
\end{align*}

in terms of $\mathbf{H_{1}^{}H_{1}^{T}}$ and $\mathbf{H_{2}^{}H_{2}^{T}}$.

Is (*) correct?

Comment: Searching *block matrix multiplication* will  shed more light on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is correct! Note that the three matrices summed in your expression (*) are all of dimension $k$ by $k$.